# Bge action editor fade out

Tags: animation, game-engine, logic-bricks

I'm making a fighting game in the game engine, and I have 2 action actuators. One is always playing an idle animation on layer 1, and the other plays the attack animation when I press w on layer 0. As I can't always be sure the idle animation will be on frame 1 when the attack starts, I have it blend in to the attack animation, and it looks fine.  However, when the attack ends, it snaps back to whatever frame the idle animation was on. Is there a way to blend back to the idle animation or assure it will be on frame 1 when the animation ends? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Add a Boolean property to it to keep track if it's active.
A Boolean is a simple True / False variable.

Have the idle animation loop while True,
then reset to the first frame when False.

Use a Property Sensor to check it's value.
https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/game_engine/logic/properties.html

Comment: And I assume on the actuator which resets it to frame 1, you have that fade in as well?